# Proving the equivalence of the following statements

Tags: logic

I need to prove that the following logic statements are equivalent using the algebraic laws of logic.

$(1) ¬p ⇔ q$

$(2) (p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q)$

I know for $(1)$ I can transform it into $(q \rightarrow ¬p) ∧ (¬q \rightarrow p)$. But I do not know how to proceed forward.